# Can I Import an excel file to an already created list? [SharePoint Foundation 2010]

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepointfoundation2010

The question says by itself. I would like to import an excel file to a list that had already created before.

I know that is possible to import it when you want to create a new list and I also know that I can import excel files programmatically. But I want to do it just using SharePoint interface or third-party applications.

Thank you all in advanced.

Comment: This one should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013412/tool-to-import-excel-sheet-data-to-sharepoint-list

Comment: Hi @Lucas-S, my answer on the SharePoint SE covers this exact scenario and is very thorough and tested. (*also linked on the question Douglas linked to*).
**Answer**: [Import/Copy/Paste Data from Excel into Existing SharePoint List](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/224375/44163).