# Tool to import Excel sheet data to Sharepoint list

Tags: excel, list, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

Are there any tools to import Excel sheet data to Sharepoint list ? 
I have found a [tool](http://www.rddevsolutions.com/Pages/Magic/MagicScreenshots.aspx#) to do that. Are there any alternatives to do this task?

[should be support any Excel version and any SharePoint version]

Comment: Hi @devan, I'm sure you're WAY past this by now :P but I have a very thorough and tested solution to a related question on the SharePoint SE.

**Answer**: [Import/Copy/Paste Data from Excel into Existing SharePoint List](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/224375/44163).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO

Simple copy/paste form Excel to DataSheet view can cover simpler scenarios (if you are copying text and/or numeric values)
If you need to copy some other data like usernames things can get difficult.

[Bulk copy and paste into a SharePoint List](http://clintoncherry.wordpress.com/2008/02/27/bulk-copy-and-paste-into-a-sharepoint-list/)

One alternative is to code your own solution using eg. console application and web services (2007 and 2010) or using client object model (2010). 
It is not difficult to even write PowerShell script to do some specific and/or semi-generic import job.

There are so many different possibilities (eg. how excel file is formatted) that finding universal tool is not an easy task. If you are able to make some Excel formatting standards then developing own solution is much more effective then buying some robust universal tool.

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint have OOB features to import the excel sheet.

you can check it over here.

http://sharepointbuzzer.com/2010/10/22/import-excel-sheet-as-sharepoint-list/

Answer (score 0):

Copy the data from excel and open the list in Datasheet view in **IE Browser** and then paste it in second column.